# This sonar rule is not triggered

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

I've just installed the latest version of SonarLint and launched a full SonarLint analysis on the code of our new trainee who has put some non-static non-injected members in a Spring singleton just like in this example :

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorld {

  private String name = null;

  @RequestMapping("/greet", method = GET)
  public String greet(String greetee) {

    if (greetee != null) {
      this.name = greetee;
    }

    return "Hello " + this.name;  // if greetee is null, you see the previous user's data
  }
}
```

https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/spring/RSPEC-3749

So I was hoping that SonarLint would detect it, but no (I have other advices, but nothing about this).

Is this rule part of a special set which need to be activated in some conf somewhere ?

Answer (score 1):

As you intuitively thought, rule [squid:S3749](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/spring/RSPEC-3749) is not part of the quality profile by default (usually called *SonarWay*). It consequently won't be executed with a fresh install of SonarLint, without proper configuration.

From there, you have two options to enable the rule:

- Connect SonarLint to a [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org) instance or [SonarCloud](https://sonarcloud.io/about), which would allow you to configure and synchronize quality profiles for all your projects automatically, executing the rules which are expected for each projects
- With latest versions of SonarLint (I tried with version 4.1 for eclipse), you should be able to enable rules directly through the plugin configuration, but this won't be shared with others working on the project.

Note that unfortunately, there is currently no way on https://rules.sonarsource.com/ to see the information about quality profiles (I'm making the internal feedback right now in order to maybe fix this in the future)

Comment: Ok, thanks, this is useful but maybe a bit light for a Sonar newbie like me : what would be the name of the "quality profile" to pick ? What is the process to pick the good rule in SonarLint when you can just tick/untick rules in an unordered, not numeroted, not classified list of hundred of rules ?

Comment: The rules enabled by default corresponds to the _SonarWay_ quality profile, as described in SonarQube instances or SonarCloud. These are the rules SonarSource thinks are always valid in all circumstances. All the other rules usually depends of the context/project, or might be controversial. To me, the best way to approach this would be to setup a SonarQube instance, define your own quality profile and populate it with rules in the dedicated UI, which have been thought for that purpose. SonarLint UI is only there for advanced users willing to enable/disable some specific rules they know about.

Comment: @Tristan could you accept my answer? I slightly edited it to make it more explicit, and I'm not sure there is much to add to the topic.

Comment: Sure, your answer is clear.  I was hoping the tool to be more like Checkstyle.

Comment: Ok Michael, so now I had some time and I installed a SonarQube server. I've created a "project" using a quality profile called "my way" copied from "sonar way", and I've bound my local project to my sonarqube project, as you suggested. I launch the analysis locally, then deactivate a few rules in "my way" and launch it again (after removing all items). The result is my distant quality profile is totally ignored, deactivated rules are still triggered.

Comment: To sum it up, after many tests : What ever rules I put in my custom quality profile, even if I set it to default quality profile, "sonar way" quality profile is always used.

Comment: Ok, I know what this SonarLint bug is about : when you bind your eclipse project to a SonarQube project using right click on eclipse project, it doesn't download the rules. Unbinding re-binding won't force the download of the rules as well. The only way to use your custom server rules is to open the "SonarLint Bindings" view in Eclipse, and then click on "update all projects bindings". If you update your answer with this informations, I can validate it.

Comment: Please report it in our community forum: https://community.sonarsource.com/